# change position of UITabbarController's Tabbar

Tags: iphone, sdk, tabbar, customization, tabbarcontroller

I am working with TabBarController application and my requirement is to add a TabBar at the top of the window rather than default bottom. Can somebody help to add the TabBar at the top of the window while using UITabbarController rather than simple tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not permitted when using `UITabBarController`. From the official docs, about `tabBar` property: 
"You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view throws an exception. To configure the items for your tab bar interface, you should instead assign one or more custom view controllers to the viewControllers property. The tab bar collects the needed tab bar items from the view controllers you specify.".